# Where did Nami get her Clima-tact while fighting Absalom?

Tags: one-piece

During Thriller Bark Arc., when Absalom is having marriage ceremony with Nami for the second time after being interrupted by Sanji, Lola appears and once again the ceremony is interrupted and Absalom hits Lola. After that Nami brings out her Clima-tact and attacks Absalom with thunder tempo.

Now since Nami was unconscious and her dress was changed by zombies, where did she get her tact to fight Absalom?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official answer but I have an idea:

She always wears a girdle around her leg where she keeps her clima-tact, the zombies probably didn't think it would be something relevant or dangerous and let her keep it on her when they changed her.

Comment: Isn't sometimes her dress too small for the girdle